# How to read headers from body of SOAP on NET 7?

Tags: c#, soap

How to read headers from body in SOAP on NET 7?

This is an example of body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthSoapHeader xmlns="https://someurl.ru/">
      <Login>Login1</Login>
      <Password>Password1</Password>
    </AuthSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <MethodName xmlns="https://someurl.ru/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to read it directly from request body using IHttpContextAccessor, but it always empty. I'm using SoapCore library, but didn't find any approuches to read Login and Password from body' headers. Advice some ways or libraries to do it on NET 7